# Django form not valid

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to POST data from a form in Django and when I click submit it doesn't get into the POST. I've already done a few POSTs using Django and they are working fine. Here, the first time the template is rendered it gets into the NO POST, which is correct. But then, when submitting the form it says NOT VALID.

*urls.py*

```
url(r'^traps/view/', 'servicios.views.viewtraps'),
```

*forms.py*

```
class LimitQueryForm(forms.Form):

    limit = forms.CharField(label='Nº de Resultados a Mostrar', max_length=250)
```

*template*

```
<form action="/services/traps/view/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_limit }}   
    <button type="submit" value="btn_limit_val" name="btn_limit_name">Aceptar</button>    
</form>
```

*views.py*

```
def viewtraps(request):

    connect_mysql = mdb.connect(*)
    cursorMYSQL = connect_mysql.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursorMYSQL.execute("""select eventname,eventid,trapoid,enterprise,community,hostname,agentip,category,severity,uptime,traptime,formatline,timestamp from snmptt order by id desc limit 500""")
    b = cursorMYSQL.fetchall()
    connect_mysql.close()

    form_limit = LimitQueryForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form_limit.is_valid():

            limit = "VALID"

            dictionary = RequestContext(request, {"buffer_data": b, "form_limit": form_limit, "limit": limit})
            return render_to_response("viewtraps.html", dictionary)

        else:

            limit = "NOT VALID"

            dictionary = RequestContext(request, {"buffer_data": b, "form_limit": form_limit, "limit": limit})
            return render_to_response("viewtraps.html", dictionary)

    else:   

        limit = "NO POST"

        dictionary = RequestContext(request, {"buffer_data": b, "form_limit": form_limit, "limit": limit})
        return render_to_response("viewtraps.html", dictionary)
```

I know some users are telling me that I shouldn't use django this way, there are reasons why I'm doing it this way, please avoid commenting on that as it's not the issue right now. Thanks!

Comment: what does `form_limit.errors` say?

Comment: You mean if I put it here what I get?

 `<form action="/services/traps/view/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

          {{ form_limit.errors }}
          {{ form_limit }}   

          <button type="submit" value="btn_limit_val" name="btn_limit_name">Aceptar</button>

       </form>`

Comment: Or just check your debugger window... theres a field on a form that says what errors there are. Most likely cause is that your form limit is a new instance of the form without any of your values passed in it

Comment: How can I check the debugger?? What do you mean is a new instance?

Comment: That would depend on what IDE you are using, most have a way to set breakpoints and look at values.

Comment: what are you doing with django? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the initialization of the `form_limit`, which is being created without reading the request parameters. Try instead:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_limit = LimitQueryForm(request.POST)
    ...
else:
    form_limit = LimitQueryForm()
```

For reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view

Answer (score 0):

cleaner..

```
def viewtraps(request):
    # ... db connections        
    form_limit = LimitQueryForm(request.POST or None) #<--- this was your typo
    if form_limit.is_valid():
        limit = "VALID"
        dictionary = RequestContext(request, {"buffer_data": b, "form_limit": form_limit, "limit": limit})
        return render_to_response("viewtraps.html", dictionary)
    else:
        limit = "NOT VALID"
        dictionary = RequestContext(request, {"buffer_data": b, "form_limit": form_limit, "limit": limit})
        return render_to_response("viewtraps.html", dictionary)

    dictionary = RequestContext(request, {"buffer_data": b, "form_limit": form_limit, "limit": limit})
    return render_to_response("viewtraps.html", dictionary)
```